# Is it a good practice to send with the logger between methods and classes?

Tags: logging

I am in this project where all the methods takes a logger and a string saying what is happening. For examle doFoo(Logger log, String doingBar, Object foo, Object bar). After that it is usualy some log messages printing doingBar + some more.

So the objects foo and bar is what is just needed, the other two is just for the log message, they say they have it like this so that you can see what happend before you came to this class. Is this a good practice?

I am use to that each class has its own logger and that you follow what is happening in the system by logging what is necescary and then have some sessionId so that you can follow what has happend.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: They do know about Aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its the best approach.

I would go for having a separate logger per class, so all methods on the class share it, and the logger can add class information to the trace (like the class name).

Or you can also use a singleton Logger if you want to share it between all classes.

If you are only logging method entry/exit and you use a IoC Container, you may want to have a look at Interceptors, that could allow you to do that same thing easily.

Answer (score 0):

Give [ReflectInsight](https://insightextensions.codeplex.com/) a try. They actually have a method called TraceMethod just for this purpose.

```
    static void SomeMethod()
    {
        ReflectInsight ri1 = RILogManager.Default;

        using (ri1.TraceMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod))
        {
            // your code ...

            ri1.SendWarning("some warning");
            ri1.SendJSON("some json object", jobj);
        }
    }
```

If you don't like to liter you code everywhere as noted above, you can use the PostSharp Extension library for RI, which uses AOP.

http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20PostSharp%20Extension&referringTitle=Documentation

1. The Live Viewer alone can receive 80,000 msg/sec
2. Live memory footprint is small as most msgs are cached on hard drive
3. Has Auto Save/Auto Purge capabilities.
4. Destinations: TextFile, BinaryFile, Live Viewer, Event Log, custom Destinations and more...
5. Can easily use NLog, Log4net, EntLib, Common Logging frameworks to map to RI's Framework (However, you will lose the ability to log rich details such as Datasets, Collections, etc).

[image]

DISCLAIMER: I don't directly work for ReflectSoftware but I'm one of the main developers that help build ReflectInsight. My main goal is help anyone with their logging framework needs and only respond to stackoverflow questions that are applicable in such regard.